# Where are M.2 USB devices?

Tags: usb-3, m.2

The [M.2 wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2) states that M.2 supports PCIe 3.0 (up to 4 lanes), SATA 3.0, and USB 3.0. Why is it, then, that despite seeing PCIe and SATA devices I never see any USB 3.0 M.2 devices?

Comment: You mean something like this -https://www.startech.com/au/HDD/Enclosures/m2-ssd-enclosure~SM2NGFFMBU33 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has changed since Mini PCIe. WiFi cards with Bluetooth still have their Bluetooth component interface with the host system via USB. For example, look at the [Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265](https://ark.intel.com/en/products/94150/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-8265#tab-blade-1-0-3) package specifications. It specifies both PCIe and USB.

Other than that, some WWAN cards may probably use it.

/edit: Yeah, here’s one: [Huawei MU736](https://consumer.huawei.com/solutions/m2m-solutions/en/products/tech-specs/mu736-en.htm). It uses USB 2.0 to communicate with the host system. It uses some additional pins to talk with the SIM card. The SIM card is inserted at a user-accessible location, which may be quite some distance from the WWAN card.